# Jquery datatables in razor view with thousands of rows/records

Tags: c#, jquery, json, razor, datatables

I'm developing a project that, inside a razor view, calls an external server and retrieves a json file (*WebRequest*, *StreamReader on response*) that I use to build a table.

**I don't have access to the database that generates the json files; those are created by another company and I have only the link to the json file.**

The table is dynamic and I don't know the number of columns and rows until I start reading the json file that gives me the number of columns and rows in the first fields.

What I'm doing is to create the html of the datatable in my razor code, ie:

```
// table header: start
_datatable = "<div class='dataTable'> <table id='gdtTable' class='display nowrap' style='width:100%'> <thead> <tr>";
```

... and so on... when I have all the html fixed I render the datatable through jquery in the script section. Also, some of the values in the json are subtables that are rendered in a dynamic modal.

The code works like a charm while I have tables with a few hundred rows, but some of the json files render tables of thousands of rows, and I have the user stuck waiting for the html to be built at runtime.

Is there any hint/suggestion on how to start rendering the first few hundred rows while the full html is being created?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you're using js to render HTML so that it can be converted to a [tag:datatables] - then you're adding too much overhead.  Instead, use JS to reformat the data into the format expected by datatables and pass directly.  If you have paging on your datatable (and why wouldn't you) then it will only render the html needed for that page.  It's the rendering->html->convert to datatables that takes the time.

Comment: Equally, you could use datatables ajax calls to load only the data needed - while you'll be loading the whole json, datatables can tell you which page/rows it wants and you can cut/slice/splice the json data accordingly.   Whether it's better to load the whole data into datatables or a page at a time (and re-loading the json each time) will depend on your use case and how your users use the data.  Probably best to load the json (directly into datatables) rather than keep reloading it, but providing another option.

Answer (score 0):

@freedomn-m
Thanks, in the end I followd you advice for "*If you have paging on your datatable (and why wouldn't you) then it will only render the html needed for that page.*" for the first data in the datatable and "*use JS to reformat the data into the format expected by datatables and pass directly*" many of the data is in a child datatable that is rendered in a modal view, so it's processed with jquery only when the user wants to load the specific data